# Create a SOCKS5 client using "net" module

Tags: go

I am working on creating my own SOCKS5 proxy client. I'm trying to make it without any 3rd modules (Only use "net", I have made a HTTP proxy client with it). Can anyone help me?
The SOCKS5 client function is looks like this:

```golang
func NewSocks(socks5Address string, websiteAddress string) (net.Conn, err)
```

Comment: FWIW, the net/http [Transport](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) has built in support for socks5.

Comment: *"Can anyone help me?"* - This is not a useful problem description. Since it is unclear what exactly you need help with, no help can be provided.

Comment: Go read at GO pkg documentation, I am sure there is some explanation for your question. The keyword is "Transport"